# Element inside div not submitting

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Why this code doesn't work? I have

```
<script>
//script to retrieve a list from a page and place it inside a div.       
</script>

//This is the list on the otherpage.
<select name='timing' id='timing'> Some Options </select>
```

The div in which it is placed

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="insert.php">
<div id="time"></div>
//some more elements and a submit button

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On submit the data should go to a php page which inserts data into the databas

```
<?php
  session_start();  //Use this to include session variables
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","clinic","myclinic","myclinic");// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $query = "INSERT INTO appointment(username, doctor, day, time) VALUES('$_SESSION[username]', '$_POST[doctor]', '$_POST[day]', '$_POST[timing]')";

  // So on.
```

The problem is the form submits all the values except the one placed inside the div
Any ideas? I've been stuck on this for a long time.

Comment: "The problem is the form submits all the values except the one placed inside the div Any ideas?" What's inside the div?

Comment: I load the drop down list from time.php on "change" event into the div

Answer (score 2):

the form dont submit div .

the form submit inputs value

change your div to an input

```
    <input type="time" name="time" />
```

this is HTML5 Time Input

some [referense for time input types](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp)

Comment: Thank you for replying. My problem is I cannot load an element from another page into an input type with jquery.

Comment: from another page ? sorry this is other question at all. show your code in other page and the page  you are receiving and edit your question and put your second question .